# OctoberCMS | Paste relation attibute into a hidden input

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend, octobercms-plugins, october-form-controller

[image]

Imagine that I have a relation field, and I want to store that relation **and also** an atribute `name` of the chosen relation into a hidden input.

Example: Into a relaion field I choose a project with `name` "Something Cool", I want to store "Something Cool" into the hidden input `info`.

How can I do that?

(I need that because of a sorting... I can't access to a relation)[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `dependsOn` option for the field to set the value described [here](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#field-dependencies):

```
project_id:
    label: Projecto
    type: relation
    nameFrom: name
sorting_field:
    type: text
    dependsOn: project_id
    cssClass: hidden # this is a helper class from storm.css to set the visibility to hidden
```

And the set the value in the `fitlerFields()` function described [here](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#filter-form-fields)